# How to get Duration of all Youtube Videos by calling YouTube API in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-api, youtube-data-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to get the duration of each video in the list after calling `youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");`
Following is my code

```
var youtubeService = new YouTubeService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                ApiKey = "API Key",
                ApplicationName = this.GetType().ToString()
            });

            var searchListRequest = youtubeService.Search.List("snippet");
            searchListRequest.MaxResults = 30;
            var searchListResponse = searchListRequest.Execute();
```

I read that the duration is in the content details of the video but the content Detail is null of each video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After checking the documentation for [search.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list) you will see that it returns a list of  [search#resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search#resource)

```
{
  "kind": "youtube#searchResult",
  "etag": etag,
  "id": {
    "kind": string,
    "videoId": string,
    "channelId": string,
    "playlistId": string
  },
  "snippet": {
    "publishedAt": datetime,
    "channelId": string,
    "title": string,
    "description": string,
    "thumbnails": {
      (key): {
        "url": string,
        "width": unsigned integer,
        "height": unsigned integer
      }
    },
    "channelTitle": string,
    "liveBroadcastContent": string
  }
}
```

Which does not contain any information about the duration of the video.   The information you are looking for does not apear to be returned by this method.

## video list

Only [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) which contains a [video.resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) will give you the duration of a video

```
 {
      "kind": "youtube#video",
      "etag": "U-t7IORpXf52WZSn6hBzfgm6WLo",
      "id": "XOIZZEdfrfA",
      "contentDetails": {
        "duration": "PT8M51S",
        "dimension": "2d",
        "definition": "hd",
        "caption": "false",
        "licensedContent": true,
        "contentRating": {},
        "projection": "rectangular"
      }
```

[image]

Comment: Do you know that by which method can I get the duration of the video?

Comment: Only [videos.list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) which contains a [video.resource](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos#resource) will give you the duration of a video

Comment: Thankyou very much, I tried youtubeService.Videos.List("contentDetails") and only then I get the details of the video like duration.